# Canvas is flickering, img.src access

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I got a game with falling pics
I push() the next func into an array
and my pics `var bulletin`are flickering, so I think it's probably I draw them a lot when use update() func

```
function rect () {
    this.size = [rectSize.x, rectSize.y];
    this.imagesSrc = rand(0, 1) ? 'bulletinYes' : 'bulletinNo';
    this.position = [rand(0, w-rectSize.x), -rectSize.y];
    this.bulletinValue = (this.imagesSrc === 'bulletinYes') ? 'bulletinYesValue' : 'bulletinNoValue';
}

rect.prototype = {
    draw: function (){ 
        var bulletin = new Image();
        bulletin.src = imagesSrc[this.imagesSrc];
        ctx.drawImage(bulletin, this.position[0], this.position[2], this.size[0], this.size[2]);
    }
}
```

I've tried to put `var bulletin` outside the fuction  like so

```
var bulletin = new Image();
bulletin.src = imagesSrc[this.imagesSrc];   <= ???
function rect () {
    this.size = [rectSize.x, rectSize.y];
    this.imagesSrc = rand(0, 1) ? 'bulletinYes' : 'bulletinNo';
    this.position = [rand(0, w-rectSize.x), -rectSize.y];
    this.bulletinValue = (this.imagesSrc === 'bulletinYes') ? 'bulletinYesValue' : 'bulletinNoValue';
}

rect.prototype = {
    draw: function (){ 
        ctx.drawImage(bulletin, this.position[0], this.position[1], this.size[0], this.size[1]);
    }
}
```

but I have no idea how to change  `[this..imagesSrc]`  so it could work.
And also it is executed only once and pic are not randomizing for each pushed one.
Does anyone have any suggestion how to get rid of the flickering or change `bulletin.src = imagesSrc[this.imagesSrc];`

[here's my github link if u want to see whole script](https://github.com/YoWuzzup/ElectionGame.git)

I just started my coding path, so thanks anyone who could answer this one:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new image each time and trying to draw it before image is loaded.
Better way is prepare all images at start and just draw it.
Little changes in your code and all will work:

Prepare images:

```
var imagesSrc = {
    ballotBoxImgSrc: 'img/ballotBox.png',
    bulletinYes: 'img/yes.jpg',
    bulletinNo: 'img/no.jpg'
};

var images = {
    ballotBoxImgSrc: new Image(),
    bulletinYes: new Image(),
    bulletinNo: new Image()
}
for(let [name,value] of Object.entries(imagesSrc)) {
    images[name].src = value;
}
```

Draw:

```
rect.prototype = {
    draw: function (){ 
        var bulletin = images[this.imagesSrc];
        ctx.drawImage(bulletin, this.position[0], this.position[1], this.size[0], this.size[1]);        
    }
}
```

Comment: woooooow thanks alot Darth it looks so easy now :))))